# Android horizontal text carousel with snapping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery, horizontalscrollview

I'd like to achieve this layout:

[image]

Where I'd show a number of TextViews, the user will be able to scroll horizontally and the list will snap to the central item (which I'll be able to retrieve).

It looks like I have several options, but none of them are satisfying.

First I've researched `HorizontalScrollView`, but it only does the scrolling and no snapping.

`Gallery` is deprecated, but looks the most promising - I only need to override `getView` in the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = convertView == null ? new TextView(getActivity()) : (TextView) convertView;
    tv.setText(getItem(position));
    tv.measure(0, 0);
    int width = tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width + 100, 100));
    return tv;
}
```

The other options available is the `ViewPager`, but it looks like ViewPager prefers views that are as wide as the ViewPager itself.

Is there any wrong with using `Gallery`? I don't really like that Google deprecates a View without providing an equivalent replacement, but I'm afraid that in some future version of Android it will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, deprecated classes will not disappear. They are just not being supported any more, so if there is a bug in the class' code, nobody will bother fixing it in a future version of the API.

If Gallery doesn't work out, there are a couple of implementations of horizontal list views around the Net - just use/extend one so that you have something equivalent to [smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) for the snapping.